# Running RIK map files?

Tags: software-recommendations, linux, sharpmap

I am new to GIS.

Which program do you recommend I use to view, mark, and then print .rik map files in Linux?

Comment: I added the `sharpmap` tag to your question because, according to file-extensions.org, "A rik file extension is related to the SharpMap a geospatial application framework." If that tag isn't relevant, you can remove it by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.